# Is it possible to detect way of import of a module in python?

Tags: python, import

Imagine you have module `foo` containing variable `bar` and thread `baz` that automagically updates `bar`:

```
from threading import Thread
import sys
bar = 0
class baz(Thread):
  def run(self):
    while True:
      setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'bar', getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'bar')+1);
baz().start()
#Note: Globals is intentionally not used instead of getattr and setattr
```

Since this thread's updates won't be readable in __main__ (since ofcourse a copy is made in __main__ from the value in `foo`), would it be somehow possible to find out whether the module was imported with either `from foo import *` or `import foo`, and based on the result, change __name__ in setattr and getattr automatically to __main__? [This topic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308062/detecting-import-module-vs-from-module-import-from-module) gives a way to detect it through code in __main__, but I want the module to detect it by itself. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "of course a copy is made in `__main__` from the value in `foo`"?  That is not the case.

Comment: @BrenBarn if you import a module through `from foo import *`, the first time the variable is read from the module, its value is copied directly into __main\_\_ and thus updates to the value in `foo` won't be visible in __main\_\_, what is my main problem, since this can neither be fixed through the use of `global bar` and 'normal' assignment in the thread...

Comment: The value is not copied.  A new *name* is bound to the same value.  You can find many questions on StackOverflow about this difference.  If your module requires its users to "watch" the variable for changes, simply document that and tell users not to use `from foo import *` (although this is a fragile design that is probably better avoided).  In any case, it's probably better to ask a question about what you're actually trying to accomplish, rather than this particular technique that you think may help you accomplish it (because it probably won't).

Answer (score 0):

No.  One reason is that a module can be imported many times, from many places.  It could be imported with `import foo` in one place and `from foo import *` in another.  Nothing will "happen" on the second import (the already-imported module in `sys.modules` will be used), so your module has no way of detecting it.