# How can I access the name a module was imported as?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, module

I want to write a simple tutorial in my Python module `foo`.

If the module is imported as `foo` I would like the tutorial to call it `foo`:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.tutorial()
Please run foo.baz().
```

However, when the module is imported as `bar` - I want the tutorial to call it `bar`:

```
>>> import foo as bar
>>> bar.tutorial()
Please run bar.baz().
```

I know that neither `__name__` nor `__package__` variables would change their value on `import ... as ...`.

To be different from  [Is it possible to detect way of import of a module in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047082/is-it-possible-to-detect-way-of-import-of-a-module-in-python) - it will be enough for me to know the first alias the module is imported with.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, foolproof, or production worthy, but:

```
import inspect
import sys


thismod = sys.modules[__name__]


def imported_as():
    imported_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    for k, v in imported_frame.f_locals.items():
        if v is thismod:
            return k
    for k, v in imported_frame.f_globals.items():
        if v is thismod:
            return k


def tutorial():
    print('please call {}.baz()'.format(imported_as()))
```

A tiny explanation:

- jump up two stack frames
- look at the locals and globals to find the module object that is identical to the module

Why you should really never do this:

- it isn't foolproof:

  - `from` imports will break this
  - multiple imports of the same module will nondeterministically give only the first found name
- `inspect.currentframe` is super magical and should generally be avoided in production code

Comment: `from` imports may be handled in a similar way (looking for object identity), but I guess nested imports will break it :(

Comment: The problem with `from` imports is you have no idea what module it came from (as the only object you can check for identity is the function object itself)

Comment: yes, but then I may omit the module name in the tutorial (`please call baz()`)

Comment: ah true!  `imported_as` above will return `None` if the module isn't found (when it is a `from` import)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution to Anthony's. I believe it better handles multiple imports. `from` imports are still an issue.

```
import inspect
import re
import readline

def tutorial():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back    
    if "__file__" in frame.f_locals:
        f = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
        m = re.search(r"(([^\.]*).*)\.tutorial", f.code_context[0].strip())
        if m:
            parent,path = m.group(2),m.group(1)
            if inspect.ismodule(frame.f_locals[parent]):
                print "Please run {}.baz()".format(path)
                return
        print "Verify import and run foo.baz()"
    else:
        loc = frame.f_locals
        glo = frame.f_globals
        local_foo = [(k, v.__name__)for k,v in loc.items() if inspect.ismodule(v) and v.__name__=="foo"]
        global_foo = [(k, v.__name__)for k,v in glo.items() if inspect.ismodule(v) and v.__name__=="foo"]
        if local_foo and set(local_foo)==set(global_foo):
            print "Please run {}.baz()".format(global_foo[-1][0])
        elif local_foo and global_foo:
            print "Please run {}.baz() in local scope or {}.baz()".format(local_foo[-1][0], global_foo[-1][0])
        elif local_foo:
            print "Please run {}.baz() in local scope".format(local_foo[-1][0])
        elif global_foo:
            print "Please run {}.baz()".format(global_foo[-1][0])
        else:
            n = readline.get_current_history_length()
            h = [str(readline.get_history_item(i)) for i in range(n)] + [readline.get_line_buffer()]
            h.reverse()
            for i in h:
                matches = re.findall(r"([A-Za-z0-9_-]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*)\.tutorial", i)
                for match in matches:
                    if _baz_check(glo, match[0]):
                        print "Please run {}.baz()".format(match[0])
                        return
            print "Verify import and run foo.baz()"


def _baz_check(d, path):
    path = path.split(".")
    if path[0] not in d:
        return False
    cur = d[path[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(path)):
        if not hasattr(cur, path[i]):
            return False
        cur = getattr(cur, path[i])
    return hasattr(cur, "__name__") and cur.__name__ == "foo" and hasattr(cur, "baz")

def baz():
    print "Baz"
```

```
import foo
foo.tutorial()
import foo as bar
bar.tutorial()

def f():
    import foo as local_foo
    local_foo.tutorial()

f()
from foo import tutorial
tutorial()
import mod
mod.foo.tutorial()
from mod import foo as dum
dum.tutorial()
```

```
Please run foo.baz()
Please run bar.baz()
Please run local_foo.baz()
Verify import and run foo.baz()
Please run mod.foo.baz()
Please run dum.baz()
```